# Install npm install, gulp and bower for multiple user in a shared Debian development environment

Tags: node.js, debian, npm, gulp, multi-user

I have dev `server` (on `debian`) witch is used by several developers, and each dev has his own profile user with `ssh` access and `vhost`.

I want allow them to use `npm install`, `gulp` and `bower` for their project, but I don't know how to make a clean and nice install of this tools.

What are the best practices?

Answer (score 0):

`postinstall` in `package.json` is useful if you just want to make the environment at once.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "postinstall": "bower install && gulp build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

with gulpfile.js like below.

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');

gulp.task('build',  function(){ return runSequence('clean', ['html', 'coffee', 'css']); });
gulp.task('clean',  function(){ ... );
gulp.task('html',   function(){ ... );
gulp.task('coffee', function(){ ... );
gulp.task('css',    function(){ ... );
```

Then `$ npm install` would run `bower` and `gulp`, too.